# Find LineStrings with common segments in PostGIS 2.3

Tags: postgis, linestring, spatial-relationship

I would like to find LineStrings with common segments ('collinear', i.e. LineStrings that have 2 or more consecutive points in common) with PostGIS.

I'm not shure if I'm missing something, but `ST_Touches` as well as `ST_Overlaps` seem to return `True` for 2 geometries that allready share only one common point.

Is there any PostGIS function I'm missing or any other solution to this?

Comment: What version of postgis are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the PostGIS documentation, Chapter 4., 4.3.6. Dimensionally Extended 9 Intersection Model (DE-9IM) (https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.3/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#DE-9IM) we read the following introduction:

*"It is sometimes the case that the typical spatial predicates (ST_Contains, ST_Crosses, ST_Intersects, ST_Touches, ...) **are insufficient** in and of themselves to adequately provide that desired spatial filter."*

This is exactly what applies here. Simply spoken, you have to examine the dimensionality of the intersection result of your two geometries. The Wikipedia article referred to in the PostGIS docs discusses this in detail: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM, which I recommend for further reading.

The `OVERLAPS` pattern for `dim(a) == dim(b) == 1` (two LineStrings) would be `'1*T***T**'` [(11) in the Wikipedia article], so a query like

```
... WHERE ST_Relate(a.geom, b.geom, '1*T***T**')
```

should give you the desired result.

Comment: I'd add only that because `ST_Relate` is so generic, it's not able to take advantage of a spatial index in any way. But if you know that your relationship involves intersection, as this one does, you can manually add an index check back into your query: `WHERE a.geom && b.geom AND ST_Relate(a.geom, b.geom, ....`

Answer (score 4):

[ST_Touches](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Touches.html) only returns true for lines that intersect start or end points, not the space along the line, so it should not work on for your case, as expected. [ST_Overlaps](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Overlaps.html), however, should work exactly as you are intending:

```
SELECT ST_Overlaps('LINESTRING(0 0, 2 0)'::geometry,
                   'LINESTRING(1 0, 3 0)'::geometry)

>>> t

SELECT ST_Overlaps('LINESTRING(0 0, 2 0)'::geometry,
                   'LINESTRING(1 0, 2 1, 2 0, 3 0)'::geometry)

>>> f
```

I just tested it both on PotGIS 2.2.0 and 2.3.2, so it *should* be working on yours too. Regardless, you can go one step deeper and work with [ST_Relate](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Relate.html). This function tests for [DE-9IM topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM), so you should be able to control exactly what you want.

Specifically, you want interior-interior interaction, so your matrix should look something like '1********' (the other cells will depend on whatever other topological restrictions you may have). Notice that this also accepts lines being completely within another, a special case of collinearity, where ST_Overlaps does not.

```
SELECT ST_Overlaps('LINESTRING(0 0, 2 0)'::geometry,
                   'LINESTRING(1 0, 2 0)'::geometry)

>>> f

SELECT ST_Relate('LINESTRING(0 0, 2 0)'::geometry,
                 'LINESTRING(1 0, 2 0)'::geometry,
                 '1********')

>>> t
```

If not even ST_Relate is working, then you might have topological problems with your data.